# How to / Orientation to build a specific type of chart using library chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm working on a project that uses chart.js and I received a new demand that consists of making a report with some particularities and after researching the library documentation I did not figure out how to perform the graphic of the image below. I would like guidance or a way to find this answer.

I have all the data information, I just need to know how to render on screen

[report to be carried out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzlKg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like it's a regular Bar chart with some funky labeling. You could do this in RGraph ( https://www.rgraph.net )  with the regular Bar chart, the coords for each bar (which are stored in the .coords property) and the RGraph.text() API function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll check RGraph documentation to check the complexity and how to do this funky labels and then try to moving to another chart framework

Comment: i'll make you an example tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I built this chart using rgrah